# Editing the Joomla Login Form

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, form, editing

I had installed a template from joomshaper. 
I'm trying to edit the login form of it. I already try to overwrite the mod_login/.../default.html file, but the form used by the template is not being overwritten.

I also tried to overwrite the k2_user default.php file but still, not working.

The website does not have any module of type "k2_user" or "Login_form" activated in the site view only at the Administrator view.

If I activated a module of type k2_user I can see the modifications made in the rewritten file, but I can't in the login form used by the template.

Comment: did you mean default.php?

Comment: Can you confirm the page you are trying to change is using mod_login instead of the login view of com_users?

Comment: How can I confirm? because the website is not using any module of type k2_user or Login_form, only in the Administrator view of the Module Manager UI I can see a module of type login_form activated.

I already tried to modify the **default.php** inside **components\com_users\views\login\tmpl** and still not working.

Comment: can you post URL?

Comment: I can't..! Still in my local machine.

Comment: does the local URL (without SEF) have option=com_users&view=login or ...?

Comment: that's the URL : .../index.php/pt/component/users/?view=login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a template override for the com_users login view.  Try modifying the **/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default.php**

Comment: But something to note, There's no **html/com_users** folder inside the template. 
so I created a new one, and overwrite the **default_login.php**. 
thank you for your tip.

Comment: Glad that helped.  It's pretty common to have to create new folders in /html/.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the classes for the fields for password and login, you will need to  change the xml file -  components / com_users / models / forms / login.xml

Handy if you want to use Bootstrap styling for example. Here's the xml for the username field, where you see class, just add an additional CSS class as required 
e.g. form-control

```
<field
            name="username"
            type="text"
            label="COM_USERS_LOGIN_USERNAME_LABEL"
            class="form-control validate-username"
            filter="username"
            size="25"
            required="true"
            validate="username"
            autofocus="true"
        />
```